# Average value of $e^{-x}$ from $0$ to $\infty$

Tags: calculus, average

I just signed up for this site so I hope I'm doing this right.

I've been having trouble wrapping my head around the average value of the function $e^{-x}$ from 0 to $\infty$. I know that the average value of a function is:

> $$\bar f =\frac{\int_a^b{f(x)dx}}{\int_a^b{dx}}=\frac{\int_a^b{f(x)dx}}{b-a}$$

And when a is 0 and b is $\infty$:

> $$\frac{\int_0^\infty{f(x)dx}}{\int_0^\infty{dx}}$$

And taking the limit since the integral is improper:

> $$\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^b{f(x)dx}}{\int_0^b{dx}}$$

When I evaluate the average value of the function $e^{-x}$ I get a result of zero (one over infinity) by taking the following steps:

> $$\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^b{e^{-x}dx}}{\int_0^b{dx}}=\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{-e^{-x}|_0^b}{x|_0^b}=\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{-e^{-b}+1}{b}=0$$

While this makes some mathematical sense to me (Unless I made a mistake in which case please let me know!) I'm puzzled on how the average value of this function can be zero when all defined values of the same function are greater than zero. Does this conclusion make any sense or am I off-track entirely?

Comment: Why do you apply L'Hopital ? $\lim_{b\to\infty}-e^{-b}+1=1$

Comment: Right, I forgot about that part of the theorem. I'll edit the post. Still the,n if the numerator goes to one and the denominator goes to $\infty$ the average value of the function would still be $\frac{1}{\infty}$, so zero, which still leads me exactly where I started. EDIT: Thanks for the title edit too, I didn't realize code could go in there.

Comment: Why shouldn't make sense? From your definition 
$$
\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^b{f(x)dx}}{\int_0^b{dx}}
$$
you have a bounded numerator and a diverging denominator! What other can you expect?

Comment: Confusion is understandable, but for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, surely you agree "most" of $e^{-x}$ is less than $\epsilon$ on $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: @GuestDiego So does that mean the average value theorem doesn't work over an infinite domain? What's confusing me is how the average value of this function is zero when every value of said function is greater than zero.

Comment: @hardmath Yes I do agree with that. The function is comprised mostly of really small numbers. I'm just trying to piece together why the average of a set of numbers is lower than every number in the set.

Comment: What do you mean with the average value theorem?

Comment: Well, using the definition you gave, that's the result you get. In fact, you could have saved yourself some thought and directly define the average of $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ as $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1x\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$$ basically, it's the number $\alpha$ such that $\alpha x$ best represents the asymptotical behaviour of the antiderivative of $f$. If the antiderivative of $f$ has a limit as $x\to\infty$, then the average of $f$ must, intuitively, be $0$.

Comment: @ GuestDiego $$\bar f =\frac{\int_a^b{f(x)dx}}{\int_a^b{dx}}$$ is what I've been taught gives the average value of a function.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli ah! That makes a lot more sense when worded like that. I've never thought of it like that but it's a much better qualitative explanation of what the average function meant in the first place. Thanks a ton, you've saved me quite a bit of headeache.

Comment: Average is a somewhat misleading term to describe the limit of the averages over finite intervlals.  It is unsurprising that a sequence of positive values can have a zero limit.  But the semi-infinite interval $[0,\infty)$ does not have a uniform probability measure, so we might refrain from asking whatabout the "average value" (expected value) of a function on this interval.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the option that the "average" is not zero. Then I guess we can agree that it must be positive. However, for every positive number $\varepsilon>0$ we can choose a large enough $b$ such that the average on $[0,b]$ is less than $\varepsilon$. Therefore, the average has to be zero.

The thing is, when using infinity one can often find some results that are not immedietely intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

I find it intuitive. We start with a value of $1=f(0)$ and decrease to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. If we find $f(n)$ for $n=0,1,2,3,...$ The more terms we choose, the more terms we have close to zero, and thus our average gets closer to $0$. Just think about it if you have $100$ numbers close to $0$ despite that $1$ in the begging isn't our average going to be close to $0$?. Although what I'm describing is more of an approximation with rectangles (width $=1$ and thus its height $f(n)$ is the area), the same idea applies if you use $f(n)$ $n=0,0+h,0+2h,...$

Answer (score 1):

The definition of average value as $\overline f =\dfrac{\int_a^b{f(x)dx}}{\int_a^b{dx}}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b{f(x)dx}$ makes a key assumption: *Every value of $x$ in $[a,b]$ is equally likely*. For finite intervals, this is a perfectly acceptable model.  But it is not the only one possible, however, and for infinite intervals it is not an option at all ($x$ would have zero probability of being found in any finite interval.)

The above is formalized by saying that the *probability distribution function* $p(x)$ of $x$ is $p(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}$ for $x\in[a,b]$ and zero otherwise. In that case, the original definition is equivalent to $\bar f =\int f(x) p(x)dx$ and it is this form which generalizes. As an example, one could consider the case of $p(x)=e^{-x}$ for $x\geq 0$. Under this assumption, the average value of $x^n$ for integer $n$ is $\overline{x^n}=\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x}\,dx=n!$. Many other cases are possible, but average values of functions are defined in the same way.